# Why can't my Android Studio terminal display Chinese characters?

Tags: git, android-studio, terminal

When I use git commands on the Terminal, why are the Chinese characters not displayed properly?

Here's an example:

[image: example]

Answer (score 3):

First, add the below line to  ~/.bash_profile:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

[image: First step]

[image: Second step]

Finally, reboot your IDE

Answer (score 1):

It may be a font issue.

In Android Studio, try going to `Settings` > `Editor` > `Console Font`, then in the `Primary Font` dropdown, try selecting a different font. (You may have to `Save As` a custom scheme to select a non-default font.)

On my Mac, the Menlo font displays Chinese characters of `git log` OK.

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue too. Just change my terminal language environment to `en_US.UTF-8`, this issue was gone. Hope my workaround  help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line into ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```